# Database hierarchy, aggregation, relations in LibreOffice Base

Tags: database, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I am working on a homework project where we design a website for a store, and I have been assigned the database. This is my first database attempt. I am using LibreOffice Base for the design, and cannot find any guides on how to make subtypes. For example, for every shirt in the inventory, there'd be a different group of colors it comes in and for every different color a list of individual sizes and how many of each size is in stock. However, I can't find aggregation anywhere in "Table Relations."
So I make a table for shirts with the base information (brand, price, etc), and then a separate table with just 2 columns (size and number of units in stock --- we're letting the possibility of multiple colors wait for now). I then make a form for the shirt with the base information and a subform with 2 columns: size and number available. Both of the forms are tables rather than labeled text boxes. However, the subform for shirt size does not maintain separate information for each row in the main form (ie the one with the base information for the shirts). How the heck do I do this?

Lastly, since this is my first crack at databases, I would not be at all surprised if I'm going at it all wrong, and if so would gladly appreciate a push in the right direction or a webpage explaining how to do this that I didn't find due to not entering the correct search terms.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create linked fields in the master table.  The shirt table has a primary key; refer to that in the subordinate table.  Alternatively, create a primary key in the subordinate table and refer to it in the master table. Then, in the subform --> properties, designate the appropriate link between the master and slave fields. The functionality is described in the [LibreOffice Base handbook (p.105)](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/e/e8/BH40-BaseHandbook.pdf#page=105)

Comment: If useful, https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/93c4b069d5437645bece5e4349558055a42342700a257e247b622cb9450cf101